# How to determine or monitor apple itune app review has passed or rejected?

Tags: itunes, app-store-connect, itunes-store

I've an app that has been 6 days since I committed last time, I want to commit a new version as soon as it has been passed.
There's no email notifies from apple.
I have to check every several hours.

How to determine or monitor apple itune app review has passed or rejected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log into iTunes connect (https://itunesconnect.apple.com) and click on Manage Your Apps:

[image]

From there you can choose from your apps to determine the status.

Comment: I mean how to notify me instead of checking it all the time. Like email, a program to monitor iTunes API to check, instead of by human eyes that uses too much time

Comment: They do email you...

Comment: Oh But I had never received

Answer (score 0):

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/itunes-connect/id376771144?mt=8   Good and perfect for me I just found